# Route Model Binding Problem Does Not Seem To Be Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, route-model-binding

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I have made a table like this at Blade:

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($roles as $role)
            @if(count($role->users))
                @foreach($role->users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $role->name }} | {{ $role->label }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="{{ route('levels.destroy'  ,$user->id) }}" method="post">
                                @method('DELETE')
                                @csrf

                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                    <a href="{{ route('levels.edit' ,$user->id) }}"  class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
```

And the result perfectly showing up:

[image]

But now I got problem with **Edit** & **Delete** buttons that I have specified `$user->id` as parameter for both of them.

And when I hover over the buttons I can see the user id properly defined:

[image]

But when it comes to edit method which is using Route Model Binding, it does not find the user:

```
public function edit(User $user)
    {
        dd($user->id); // return null
    }
```

However if I do not use Route Model Binding and say this instead:

```
public function edit($id)
        {
            dd($id); // return 1
        }
```

It properly shows the user id!

I don't know why the Route Model Binding not working here, so if you know what's going wrong or how to fix this issue, please let me know...

Comment: please share your user edit route

Comment: Can you route that you define it?

Comment: @BhargavRangani `Route::resource('levels', LevelController::class);`

Comment: @Chando `Route::resource('levels', LevelController::class);`

Comment: your route is for the level model in the controller you can not access with user model

Comment: Your resource name must be match with Model in your controller.

Comment: @memite7760 check your route. you might have passed users/{id}/edit. where you should've passed users/{user}/edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the User Model which in this case doesn't know what id is, so you should be passing the `id` of the user to the edit route using either Get by passing it to the url endpoint , so now you can get it like

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        dd($id); // return null
    }
```

or by sending it as a POST form and get it like

```
public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->id); // return null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw comments, your resource controller name is not matching with your variable name "$user".

You can look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters) on official laravel docs.

In your situation, this might help;

```
Route::resource('levels', LevelController::class)->parameters([
    'levels' => 'user'
]);
```